# How to get specific element when we click on select text?

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <?php
    while ($row = $resultpelanggan->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<div class="form-check">';
        echo '<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="pelanggan' . $row['idpelanggan'] . '" value="' . $row['idpelanggan'] . '">';
        echo '&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp';
        echo '<label class="form-check-label" for="option' . $row['idpelanggan'] . '">' . $row['idpelanggan'] .'|| ' . $row['nm_pelanggan'] .'</label>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

```
<div class="col-sm-9 my-3 mb-sm-0">
    <!-- input text to store Pelanggan -->
    <Input type="text" placeholder="Nama Pelanggan  " class="form-control form-control-user" name="idpelanggan" id="getPelanggan" data-toggle="modal" readonly></input>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 my-3 mb-sm-0">
    <!-- Button Trigger Modal For Pelanggan-->
    <button type="button" class="form-control btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPelanggan">Open Modal</button>
</div>
```

```
function setSelectedPelanggan() {
    // Mengatur nilai input teks dengan opsi yang dipilih
    var selectedOption = $('input[name=optionsRadios]:checked').val();
    var optionText = $('label[for=option' + selectedOption + ']').text();
    $('#getPelanggan').val(optionText);

    // Menutup popup
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
}
```

[image]

I need to show the elements generated from the keys `idpelanggan` and `nm_pelanggan` on modal popup, but I only need the element with the key `idpelanggan` to store in input text.  How can I do this?

Comment: `selectedOption` should already contain the ID. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/510vzdsL/

Comment: Consider posting a properly indented code when posting a question, to make it easier for other developers to read it. Use tools such as https://codebeautify.org/php-beautifier.

Comment: @ADyson Perhaps I am misunderstanding, but where's the duplicate?  Your link just leads back here.

Comment: @Daedalus sorry I seem to have had a brain melt and thought this was a repost of a previous question, when in fact it just reappeared in the feed - probably due to your edit. Shows you shouldn't comment from your phone while also doing 3 other things...

Comment: @ADyson I probably should have clarified in a comment that I attempted to make the title/question clearer, so my bad there as well.